# how to use python selenium to click on a button recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to recursively click on a button to load customer reviews on target using python selenium. As an example, using this product:
https://www.target.com/p/vanity-fair-everyday-white-napkins-250ct/-/A-14739020
So at the bottom of the page with customer reviews, there is a button to "load 8 more" reviews. I wanted to simulate this in selenium by opening the product page, scrolling to the bottom of the page to ensure the element loads, then click() on the xpath for the element like so:

```
from time import sleep
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

class targetProduct:
    '''given a product page, return all of the customer reviews'''
    def __init__(self):
        #start chrome driver
        self.mydriver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver.exe')
        #enter a product page URL with reviews
        self.productpage = "https://www.target.com/p/vanity-fair-everyday-white-napkins-250ct/-/A-14739020"

    def open_page(self):
        #open the product page and maximize the window
        self.mydriver.get(self.productpage)
        self.mydriver.maximize_window()
        sleep(5)

    def button_click(self):
        try:
            #scroll to the bottom of the page and sleep to ensure the button loads
            self.mydriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            sleep(3)
            #click on the button to load 8 more reviews
            self.mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/button').click()
            #sleep to load more reviews, then try clicking again to load addition reviews
            sleep(3)
            self.button_click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("cant find more reviews button, continuing")

tp = targetProduct()
tp.open_page()
tp.button_click()
```

It appears everything is working, except the program is not able to correctly find the "load 8 more reviews" button. I copied the xpath straight from the website as usual. Is something strange going on preventing me from directly clicking on this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified the xpath and it is working.

```
def button_click(self):
        try:
            #scroll to the bottom of the page and sleep to ensure the button loads
            LoadMore = self.mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-test='load-more-btn']/button[contains(text(),'Load')]")

            sleep(3)
            #click on the button to load 8 more reviews
            LoadMore.click()
            #sleep to load more reviews, then try clicking again to load addition reviews
            sleep(3)
            self.button_click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("cant find more reviews button, continuing")
```

Comment: thanks, this answer works. i'm still a bit unclear on why my xpath fails to work as i right clicked the element to copy the xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use this function to wait for a button so you can get rid of `sleep()`, you can implement it.

```
def wait_for(btn):
    # if the element exist return the element otherwise wait for element
    btn_handle = None
    while not btn_handle:
        try:
            btn_handle = browser.find_element_by_xpath(btn)
        except:
            btn_handle = None
```

I've made an edit for your code

```
def button_click(self, btn):
    #get button
    button = self.mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(btn)
    try:
        while button:
            #scroll to the bottom of the page and sleep to ensure the button loads
            self.mydriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            sleep(3)
            button.click()
            print("Button clicked")
    except:
        print("cant find more reviews button, continuing")



tp = targetProduct()
tp.open_page()
tp.button_click('//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/button')
```

Also check this [Selenium Waits Doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) if you want to use selenium buildin functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have async loading, wait until the element is loaded and ready for interaction, use the builtin stuff. Flat `time.sleep(3)` may not be good enough, your code did work for me as it is, but a slower load time may result a failure.  `expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located` allows you to have your button ready to be clicked.

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class targetProduct:
    '''given a product page, return all of the customer reviews'''
    def __init__(self):
        #start chrome driver
        self.mydriver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver.exe')
        #enter a product page URL with reviews
        self.productpage = "https://www.target.com/p/vanity-fair-everyday-white-napkins-250ct/-/A-14739020"

    def wait_for_elem_by_xpath(self, xp):
        elem = WebDriverWait(self.mydriver, 8).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xp)))
        return elem

    def open_page(self):
        #open the product page and maximize the window
        self.mydriver.get(self.productpage)
        self.mydriver.maximize_window()
        sleep(5)

    def button_click(self):
        try:
            #scroll to the bottom of the page and sleep to ensure the button loads
            self.mydriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            #click on the button to load 8 more reviews
            more_button = self.wait_for_elem_by_xpath('//*[@data-test="load-more-btn"]/button')
            more_button.click()
            #sleep to load more reviews, then try clicking again to load addition reviews
            sleep(3)
            self.button_click()
        except TimeoutException:
            print("cant find more reviews button, continuing")

tp = targetProduct()
tp.open_page()
tp.button_click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your solution. The reason I implemented the way I did is because when the comments have been fully expanded (recursively clicking the button) the button will disappear, so nosuchelementexception will trigger and the program will continue.